# Is it possible to measure inertial mass without gravity or rolling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, mass, inertia

Is there a reliable (and ideally, easy to construct+tune) method of measuring inertial mass without using gravity (e.g. weighing on a scale or a freefall apparatus or a pendulum) or rolling (e.g. pushing an object and seeing how fast it moves horizontally) for sphere-shaped objects?  The rolling requirement is because the spheres I'm using will have non-uniformly distributed mass (some may be hollow, some may be hollow, some may be solid, and some may have masses symmetrically (dodecahedrally or icosahedrally arranged weights) placed not at the center but not at the outside (effectively comprising a shell of high mass between two lower-mass volumes when viewed from the radius out.)

I'm attempting to compare the inertial mass of each sphere (same radius and same gravitational mass for each) while excluding gravitational effects (gravitational mass and moment of inertia) from the experiment.

Comment: I am not 100% but it seems equivalence principle indirectly states that gravitational mass and inertial mass are both same/identical. Otherwise, if you were accelerated with same value as g, you would feel a different weight in two cases - gravity of g, and acceleration of g. Thus you would be able to differentiate between the two, which would be violation of the principle. Based upon this, if you have gravitational mass, you also have inertial mass.

Comment: @kpv This is correct, but I want to observe it.

Comment: You can lift them in accelerated way. The force in excess of their weight, and acceleration imparted should give you inertial mass.

Comment: Lifting would use gravity.

Comment: It does not use gravity, it just counters it because it is there. And you know its value. You may hang them with a string to a horizontal bar, then speed them and measure the force to stop/retard them.

Comment: I'm looking at using extremely small (10mm diameter) spheres so friction would be an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73084/discussion-between-kpv-and-coryg).

Comment: Use centrifuge with a force transducer in the arm to measure the radial centrifugal force. Then  `m = F/ (w^2 r)`

Answer (score 1):

You could create an relative measure or scale of mass using springs. You could time the period of oscillation for a mass that's attached to a spring.

The time period of oscillation is proportional to $\sqrt{k\over m}$.

This is how they measure mass in microgravity environment.

Comment: That seems really difficult to engineer over a horizontal axis without friction becoming the dominant force.

Comment: @CoryG you could do it using air tracks a lot of experiments of these nature are done using those . The air tracks have very little friction(essentially just air friction) which can be ignored .And they come with a very well machined surface. There are ones which are for 1 and 2 dimensions(it's sorta like a ice hockey table but much much more sophisticated) . Again these kind of equipment is Very common for these experiments .

Comment: That still seems difficult to engineer (difficult to engineer and extremely high cost are interchangeable terms.)  I'm trying to find something I can put together on a budget of a few hundred dollars for the whole thing.

Comment: @CoryG If you hang the spring vertically, the gravitational effects end up canceling out and not affecting the period of oscillation.

Comment: @Acccumulation This definitely isn't correct, the period of oscillation would change under different levels of gravity and mass relative to the tension of the spring, the purpose is to measure inertial mass independent of gravitational mass then compare, not to measure gravitational mass twice and call them the same from that.

Comment: @CoryG search 'linear air track' i found one for about ₹9,600 about 200$. Or you could just do what accumulation is suggesting if that is suitable for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ShirishSrivastava Thanks, I think I'm going to go with measuring the resonant frequency of an ultrasonic transducer with a fixture containing the test object, should be a bit more reliable with less room for error.

Comment: @CoryG no bro he's correct.

Comment: @CoryG No, given Hooke's Law, F=kx. If you add a constant force f1, such as gravity, then it becomes F= -kx+f1 = -k(x-f1/k). Take the substitution u = x-f1/k and the equation is F = -ku. You get exactly the same solution, with exactly the same period. The only difference is that everything is in terms of u instead of x, and hence everything is shifted by f1/k.

Comment: @ShirishSrivastava In system with a weight bouncing on a spring against gravity it is literally mass vs gravity vs spring tension, and spring tension isn't even linear with deformation.

Comment: @Acccumulation You're using a method which assumes gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same.

Comment: @CoryG No, I'm not. The only assumptions I'm making are that Hooke's Law applies and that a constant force is applied. No assumptions about the nature of that force are made.

Comment: @CoryG it;s been a long time, how did ur experiment go :) were you able to do it? What's the accuracy upto which you wanted to measure the mass :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply rolling the spheres with the motive force applied at differing radii would allow you to compensate for differing moments of inertia. If you push through the center of mass, then the moment of inertia disappears as a factor. Also, suppose you put a known mass on one side of a rod, and an unknown mass on the other. If you can find the center of mass of the resulting system, then you can find the unknown mass.

Comment: The moment of inertia does not disappear for rolling spheres with different density profiles.  How would you determine the center of mass in the pendulum version without gravity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding you correctly, it is not like you necessarily don't want to use gravity right? Measurement just needs to be independent of gravitational mass. You could first weigh the spheres so you know what the gravitational force is. And then measure the time it takes to fall a certain distance.

Then you will know the force, the time gives you acceleration and you can compute inertial mass.

Comment: The issue there is that both measurements are done with gravitational mass.  It is believed that gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same but the purpose of the experimental setup is to confirm or deny that (as a complementary experiment to a falling mass as you've described, actually.)  Using the force of gravity (via a scale) to weigh the objects then using the force of gravity again (via acceleration of the objects dropping) would always equal the same thing regardless because both measurements rely on gravity for the result.  Also, gravity is an acceleration, not a force.

Comment: I don't see why you are measuring both times the gravitational mass.

Comment: If you think that gravity is an acceleration then I see why you might think it is measuring the same thing twice. But it isn't. Gravity is a force (in Newtonian world). So if you know the force and you know the acceleration it is producing, it will tell you the inertial mass independently of the gravitational mass.And it is not that gravitational mass is the same as inertial mass, it is that they are proportional to each other.

Comment: The mass on the scale is interpreted from the force felt by gravity (acceleration) pulling the gravitational mass (e.g. F=ma then implicitly taking out a.)  The time it takes them to fall a fixed distance is going to be the same regardless of mass (assuming negligible surface area and in turn air resistance) but is again determined by the acceleration of gravity.

Comment: Gravity as we measure it is an acceleration, gravity in theory is a force.  Measurements trump theory in reality and in speech as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: No, the scale just measures force in N. It works in zero gravity also if you press on it. All that you are assuming in the experiment that I described is that the gravitational force when it is on the scale is the same as when it is falling.

Comment: That's the point, both use gravity to determine the mass and are therefore equivalent.  You cannot use the combination of them to say inertial mass == gravitational mass.

Comment: The flaw in your reasoning is when you say that gravity is an acceleration. At that time you are mixing up the gravitational and inertial mass.

Comment: Gravity is an acceleration.

Comment: The reason you can claim that gravity is an acceleration is **because** inertial mass is proportional to gravitational mass.

Comment: No, it's because gravity isn't a force but a distortion of spacetime, the acceleration is from the tendency of objects in that spacetime to seek out places of minimum potential energy which results in an acceleration based on the amount of spacetime distortion.  Force requires both acceleration and mass, that's the literal definition of force, gravity cannot be a force because it has nothing carrying that acceleration until matter is impacted by its proximity.  Inertial mass and gravitational mass don't need too be proportional, but in fact all experiment says they are exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure inertial mass by using newtons equation or equivalence principle. Here is an example that does not use gravity. About one minute and 20 seconds into the video you will see. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU2hGIrBULA&sns=em

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Charles Bretana's suggestion, you can use a circular plate with a wall around the edge. Perhaps use two spheres at once. Position the spheres against the wall, on opposite sides to provide balance, and restrict tangential movement of the spheres relative to the plate. Now rotate the plate and measure the force against the wall from the sphere. Also measure the rotation rate and radial distance of the center of the sphere. Perhaps a modified record turntable will work. I don't know the cheapest way to measure the force against wall.